# List-image doesnt appear

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I need some help with my LI style css

http://mediafb59.fiftynine.axc.nl/

I don't know why it doesn't appear I want an image floating on the right of my sidebar links
but

and my content is getting under my sidebar...

```
    .sidebar-menu ul {
    font : 14px font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    margin : 0;
    padding : 0;
    margin-bottom : 0;
    list-style-image:url(images/menu-arrow.png);
    }
```

this methode doesnt work for me ? has someone got a simple solution for me ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are setting `padding: 0px` on `.sidebar-menu ul`. Once you remove that the arrows show. It changes the rest of your layout though.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `padding : 0;` and your arrows will appear. Then set the desired padding for ul/li.